I can't access information about which recipient clicked on my email. AWS SES SDK and PHP
I can't access information about which recipient clicked on my email. I'm using aws ses SDK and PHP. I got this information using getExportJob but it doesn't give me the sender's email address, only the sendername as in the screenshotenter image description here
I tried to use listExportJob, getExportJob, I tried to use SES with SNS, but SNS doesn't work to track the recipient's action. Quantities and shipments only.
In this screenshot that I showed , I just wanted the fromaddress to also return the sender address, which would already solve my problem
